# Feign client log level intervene with pdf binary content

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, feign

Currently with below log levels pdf file is downloading properly

```
logging:
  level:
    root: ${SERVER_LOG_LEVEL:INFO}
    com:
      abc:
        feign: DEBUG
```

but with below one config file got corrupted

```
logging:
  level:
    root: ${SERVER_LOG_LEVEL:INFO}
    com:
      abc:
        feign: INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

> Feign logging responds only to the DEBUG level.

For each Feign client, a logger is created by default.

The Logger.Level that we may configure per client indicates how much to log:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {
    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }
}
```

There are four logging levels to choose from:

1. NONE – no logging, which is the default
2. BASIC – log only the request method, URL, and response status
3. HEADERS – log the basic information together with request and response headers
4. FULL – log the body, headers, and metadata for both request and response

Please read more at : https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same problem you had, but we were seeing exactly the same symptoms: feign file download, working in debug mode, not working in info/warn/error.

In debug mode, feign's `Logger.logAndRebufferResponse()` is called at some point which reads the payload of the response and repackages it back into a new response with a ByteArrayInputStream payload.

Separately, we had a custom `HttpMessageConverter`; it turns out that it was never working properly for file downloads because the inputStream wasn't being fully read before it was closed (it was being closed at the end of `SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode()`).  It only "worked" because with log level set to debug, feign's `Logger` was magically doing the repackaging separately as part of doing request/response logging.  Fixing the custom `HttpMessageConverter` by repackaging the input stream into a `ByteArrayInputStream` worked for us.